# Trigger ng-change using Directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using ng-options to iterate some data in angularjs and when selecting value i want a selected Object , For that i have created directive..

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict  : 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        $(element).combobox({
            source: scope[attrs.reportitems],
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $timeout(function() {
                        if(attrs.reportitems=="zoneList"){
                            if(ui.item.attributes.value.value != "0") {
                                scope["update"](ui.item.attributes.value.value);
                            }
                        }
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

This will call update method in controller and it will pass the index position of data array but i want the object itself instead of index. or somehow trigger ng-change method in UI.so that i can have an Object in update Method in controller. please check this Plunker for whole Code..[Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymyetmelU7CMIuXqynvf?p=preview)

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the entire object is being passed through inside of an array when an item is selected.  You just need `res[0]` to get access to the object.  From there you have the id, tableName, and toolTip properties available.  Alternatively, you could just assign `ng-change=update(selected[0])` to get the object.

I'm curious as to why you define `$scope.selected = []` then assign `$scope.selected = res`